# Json to java objects mapping

Tags: java, json, deserialization

What is the best solution for mapping/deserialize this json:

```
 { "columns" : [ "name", "description", "id" ], "data" : [ [ "Train", "Train desc", 36 ], [ "Ship", "Ship desc", 35 ], [ "Plane", "Plane desc", 34 ] ] }
```

in to a list of objects of this class:

```
class Transport { String id; String name; String description; }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @dougEfresh The question is about JSON straightforward mapping to the java.

Comment: you can try using this : http://json.org/java/ or https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Whatever the parser you use chooses for the defaults.  In some other languages the choices are obvious, but Java has several choices each for arrays and "objects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know libraries that supports mapping between JSON Arrays ("data" is an array of arrays) and Java object fields.

The [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library let you map your JSON Array into an array of array of java String, but then you have to convert it to your object model.
You can parse your JSON into this object:

```
class DataWrapper
{
    String[] columns;
    String[][] data;
}
```

Another solution is to use the JSonReader and stream out your objects using this class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

public class TransportJSonReader implements Iterator<Transport> {

protected JsonReader jsonReader;

public TransportJSonReader(Reader reader) throws IOException
{
    jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader);
    jsonReader.beginObject();

    //columns
    jsonReader.nextName();
    jsonReader.skipValue();

    //data
    jsonReader.nextName();
    jsonReader.beginArray();

}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    try {
        return jsonReader.hasNext();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public Transport next() {
    if (!hasNext()) throw new IllegalStateException();

    try {
        jsonReader.beginArray();
        String name = jsonReader.nextString();
        String description = jsonReader.nextString();
        String id = jsonReader.nextString();
        jsonReader.endArray();
        return new Transport(id, name, description);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

}
```

It is an iterator so you can use it in this way:

```
    TransportJSonReader reader = new TransportJSonReader(new StringReader(json));
    while(reader.hasNext()) System.out.println(reader.next());
```